Should compound nouns (or modified nouns) be hyphenated when used as a modifier?
I think this is a bit different from previous questions. If I rephrase, "Topics related to charging infrastructure," as, "Charging infrastructure related topics," should I hyphenate it as "charging infrastructure-related" or "charging-infrastructure-related"?
I believe the hyphen between "infrastructure" and "related" is necessary, or at least common, and would appear if "charging" weren't in the sentence (ex. "Infrastructure-related topics"). What about the hyphen between "charging" and "infrastructure," though?

Neither: "Charging infrastructure related topics" seems to have a quite different meaning. How much will they be charged?

I think there's a duplicate of this, but it's simple. Hyphenate throughout the entire phrase. Using the pattern "peanut butter and jelly-sandwich" is, if possible, more preposterous than not hyphenating.

You have found a good example of why squeezing-it-all-into-a-tight-package makes things more complicated, not better.

So, my searching was incomplete (hard to come up with the right search terms...), but this is a duplicate. Also, @WeatherVane, "charging" here refers to the increase in the state of charge of a battery, not billing, as I think your comment implies

I realise that from the question, but on its own "Charging infrastructure related topics" is ambiguous.
